# validar campo email incluyendo dominio completo laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, email, validación

No logro encontrar la forma de validar las direcciones de email para que requiera un dominio completo.
Con poner la regla de validación de laravel valida que sea al menos tenga una letras después del arroba (ej: info@p) y necesito que al exija .com o .net (ej info@p.net)

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.8 y con un form request personalizado que dejo a continuacion

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'     => 'required|min:3',
        'surname'    => 'required|min:3',
        'email'   => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->id,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho a tu propia pregunta el que edites y agregues lo que has intentado al momento

Comment: Deje la regla con la que estoy trabajando. Pero la regla "email" solo valida que sea texto@texto y necesito que sea text@text.algo

Comment: A partir de la versión 5.8.33 la regla de validación de correo electrónico introduce la capacidad de agregar múltiples validadores de correo electrónico al verificar correos electrónicos válidos. Puedes probar/investigar cuál cubre tus requerimientos,  creo que podría ser `'email' => 'email:filter' `. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-email

Comment: 'email' => 'email:filter' era lo que necesitaba. Creia haberlo probado pero indudablemente no. Gracias.